# replacing filenames with parent folder name without changing file endings

Tags: rename, zsh, batch-rename

Im struggling replacing filenames with parent folder name and conserving the different file endings.

Example;

```
.sp1/4287/4287/iho.cst
.sp1/4287/4287/iho.dbf
.sp1/4287/4287/iho.prj
.sp1/4287/4287/iho.shp
.sp1/4287/4287/iho.shx
```

renamed to;

```
.sp1/4287/4287/4287.cst
.sp1/4287/4287/4287.dbf
        .
        .
        .
```

Im currently trying out `zsh shell` using `zmv`.

```
zmv '(*)/*' '$1/$1'
```

But this is matching all. I don't get how to escape the file endings (if possible). Also tried `rename` but without success.

Since I have multiple `sp folders` `(sp2, sp3, ..spN)` and since each `e.g. sp1/` contain a lot of subfolders like `4287` with the same type of files, Im seeking a batch solution.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

This works when in spN/XXXX/;

```
zmv '(*)/*.(*)' '$1/$1.$2';
```

---

How can I write a loop going through the `spN/XXXX/` folders and executing the above `zmv` code?

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
source ~/.zshrc

for i in ./*;
  for y in i;
    do
      zmv '(*)/*.(*)' '$1/$1.$2';
    done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with `zmv`, but I guess this will do it:

```
zmv '(*)/*.(*)' '$1/$1.$2'
```

Comment: It sure does the trick! I tried something similar but left out the last set of parentheses. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `zmv` but try this script:

```
while read file
do
    prefix=$(echo $file | sed 's|\(.*\)/.*$|\1|');
    parent=$(echo $file | sed 's|.*/\([^/]\+\)/[^/]\+$|\1|');
    child=$(echo $file | sed 's|.*/\([^.]\+\).*$|\1|');
    ext=$(echo $file | sed 's|.*/[^.]\+\.\(.\+\)$|\1|');
    mv "$prefix/$child.$ext" "$prefix/$parent.$ext"
done < <(find -type f)
```

**EDIT:** The first version doesn't work if the files or directories contains spaces.

Comment: Cheers, but seems unnecessary complicated compared to zmv.